# Does Firebase still support Mac OS X - July 2016

Tags: ios, macos, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an iOS App that uses the Firebase Realtime Database that I would like to create for Mac OS X. Does Firebase still support Mac OS X in the latest update as the Firebase console only shows the option to Add Firebase to an iOS, Android or web app.

If so, where can I find it?

Thank you

Comment: Yeah, looks like they've reduced their officially-supported platforms to just iOS, Android, and Web. Have you tried using the iOS version of the Firebase SDK in a Mac app? It might work. Alternatively, does the REST API meet your needs? It's not real-time, but it's easy to use. As a last resort, you could load a small JS app into a WebView, and use the JS version of the Firebase API.

Comment: Unfortunately the new 3.x SDK doesn't support OSX at the moment. Read a lot more about it in this Google Groups discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/gber4k8nmsI/ehd45IHeFQAJ

Comment: Firebase 2.5.1 continues to work with OS X. Here's the legacy [Getting Started Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/) which has a link to the download and also QuickStart for installing via CocoaPods. See my post in the link @FrankvanPuffelen provided above (3rd msg down in the link) for a sample pod file config. Future support for OS X is unknown at this point and we've been waiting 2 months for word so you may want to look at other options in case it's officially dropped.

Comment: CouchBase Mobile works well on OS X and OS X is officially and well supported.  They have offline storage and remote sync both self-hosted and paid hosting by them.  See https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.3/installation/ios/index.html .

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to the open source community, it's possible again to build a Firebase Realtime Database client on macOS. Details in the [GitHub repo README](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk#macos).

Comment: Click on your link, I don't understand how to continue. What I understood is we should use version 2.5.1 which used to support Mac OSX. However, I don't know how to configure firebase with this version.

Comment: See also https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk#source-pod-integration and if you have questions/issues, ask another stackoverflow question or file an issue at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues

Answer (score 1):

As Paul said, you have to follow the instructions to get the pods right from the GitHub repository.

I added these lines to my Podfile

```
pod 'FirebaseCore', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :branch => 'master'
pod 'FirebaseStorage', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :branch => 'master'
```

Then on the AppDelegate

import FirebaseCore

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't instal firebase with those links. I get this error: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore":