# Firebase as a backend service for OS X in swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, firebase

Is there anyway to use Firebase as a backend service for my OS X application for apple desktop/laptop computers?

Hope this makes sense, also what are some good options you would recommend to use for IOS/Android apps and IO X applications?

Comment: Recommending technologies is off-topic here on Stack Overflow. But the Firebase 3.x SDK don't currently support running on OSX. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276695/does-firebase-still-support-mac-os-x-july-2016

Comment: Sorry for that and thanks for the insight..

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is still an option for macOS, though it's a [community-supported project](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk) and not officially supported. For whatever reason, Google has de-prioritized it.

You can't use everything Firebase has to offer, but you can at least use it for storing/syncing data.

Just add these pods to your Podfile in a macOS app and it'll work:

```
pod 'FirebaseCore'
pod 'FirebaseAuth'
pod 'FirebaseDatabase'
pod 'FirebaseStorage'
```

If there were a more promising outlook for macOS, I'd use Firebase in a heartbeat. It covers many more app platforms than CloudKit and is (in my opinion) easier to use.